# Can't find a math formula to resize two views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

I'm having a start position like you can see on my sketch. My Map always fills up the whole screen. I just resize my tableview on top of it.

[image]

When I click on the map , the tableview resizes like you can see on my seconds sketch the left one. If I then click on the tableview, the tableview resizes.

[image]

Now the problem is that I can't find a math function that the 2 things are always equal size. Like I point out on the sketch.

This how I initialize the 2 views:

```
-(void) initMapView
{
    _mapView = [[GoogleMapViewController alloc] init];
    [self addChildViewController:_mapView];
    _mapView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width , self.view.bounds.size.height);

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer * tapGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(expandMap:)];
    [_mapView.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    [self.view addSubview:_mapView.view];
    [_mapView didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

-(void) initPOITableView
{
    _poiTableView = [[POITableViewController alloc] init];
    [self addChildViewController:_poiTableView];
    _poiTableView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer * tapGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(expandTableView:)];
    [_poiTableView.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    [self.view addSubview:_poiTableView.view];
    [_poiTableView didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

And this is my animation function:

```
- (void) expandTableView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"ExpandTableView Animation");
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
    float cellHeight = [_poiTableView getHeightForIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"Cell height %f", cellHeight );

    float navBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.2
                        options:0
                     animations:^{
                         if(_isStartUpPosition)
                         {
                             NSLog(@"StartUp");
                             _poiTableView.view.frame = CGRectMake(_poiTableView.view.frame.origin.x, _poiTableView.view.frame.origin.y - ( _poiTableView.view.frame.origin.y -  navBarHeight - 2 * cellHeight ), _poiTableView.view.frame.size.width, _poiTableView.view.frame.size.height);
                             _isMapExpanded = NO;
                             _isStartUpPosition = NO;
                         }
                         else if(_isMapExpanded)
                         {
                             NSLog(@"TableView is now being expanded");
                             _poiTableView.view.frame = CGRectMake(_poiTableView.view.frame.origin.x, _poiTableView.view.frame.origin.y - ( _poiTableView.view.frame.origin.y -  navBarHeight - 2 * cellHeight ), _poiTableView.view.frame.size.width, _poiTableView.view.frame.size.height);
                             _isMapExpanded = NO;
                         }
                     }
                     completion:nil];

}

- (void) expandMap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"ExpandMap Animation");
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
    float cellHeight = [_poiTableView getHeightForIndexPath:indexPath];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.2
                        options:0
                     animations:^{
                         if(_isStartUpPosition)
                         {
                             NSLog(@"StartUp");
                             _poiTableView.view.frame = CGRectMake(_poiTableView.view.frame.origin.x, _poiTableView.view.frame.origin.y + _poiTableView.view.frame.origin.y - cellHeight, _poiTableView.view.frame.size.width, _poiTableView.view.frame.size.height);
                             _isMapExpanded = YES;
                             _isStartUpPosition = NO;
                         }
                         else if(!_isMapExpanded)
                         {
                             NSLog(@"Map is now being expanded");
                             _poiTableView.view.frame = CGRectMake(_poiTableView.view.frame.origin.x,  _poiTableView.view.frame.origin.y + 2 * _poiTableView.view.frame.origin.y , _poiTableView.view.frame.size.width, _poiTableView.view.frame.size.height);
                             _isMapExpanded = YES;
                         }
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}
```

I just can't find the ratio between the two so they could be always the same. On every screen.

**EDIT**

This is now my map expand

```
     if(!_isMapExpanded)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"Map is now being expanded");
                  _poiTableView.view.frame = CGRectMake(_poiTableView.view.frame.origin.x,  _poiTableView.view.frame.origin.y, _poiTableView.view.frame.size.width, _shrankHeight);
                     _isMapExpanded = YES;
                     _mapView.view.frame = CGRectMake(_mapView.view.frame.origin.x,  _mapView.view.frame.origin.y, _mapView.view.frame.size.width, _expandedHeight);
                 }
```

and this is my tableview expand:

```
         if(_isMapExpanded)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"TableView is now being expanded");
                     _poiTableView.view.frame = CGRectMake(_poiTableView.view.frame.origin.x,  _poiTableView.view.frame.origin.y, _poiTableView.view.frame.size.width, _expandedHeight);
                     _mapView.view.frame = CGRectMake(_mapView.view.frame.origin.x,  _mapView.view.frame.origin.y, _mapView.view.frame.size.width, _shrankHeight);
                     _isMapExpanded = NO;
                 }
```

What I now have is, that when my tableview is going to expand, it only goes to the half of the screen and not to the top.

Comment: 1/3 seems to be a good ratio for the shrinking one. With that, the expanding one will have a 5/3 ratio, since they were identical at the beginning. You don't have to compare with each other, just shrink/expand them according to their own sizes.

Comment: Can you point me out what I need to change. Because I'm not sure that I understand it.

Comment: Sure thing, I will add as an answer soon.

Comment: +1 for the paper sketches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@property float shrankHeight;
@property float expandedHeight;
@property float normalHeight;

- (void) calculateHeights
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    // If you're going to use landscape, use width.
    normalHeight = (screenBounds.height - 44) / 2.0; // Don't forget the navigation bar, though.
    shrankHeight = normalHeight / 3.0;
    expandedHeight = normalHeight * 5.0 / 3;
}
```

After you've calculated the heights, you can use them in your animation block.

For example, if the map is going to expand, you should:

```
_poiTableView.view.frame = CGRectMake(_poiTableView.view.frame.origin.x,  _poiTableView.view.frame.origin.y + 2 * _poiTableView.view.frame.origin.y , _poiTableView.view.frame.size.width, shrankHeight);
```

And

```
_mapView.view.frame = CGRectMake(_mapView.view.frame.origin.x,  _mapView.view.frame.origin.y + 2 * _mapView.view.frame.origin.y , _mapView.view.frame.size.width, expandedHeight);
```

You will probably need to change their centres after.

Comment: So I don't need the startup if test anymore? And Do I still need the 2  * mapView ... ? Or can I just put y?

Comment: I don't think you need the startup test anymore, maybe it could be useful for calculating the center point. You will see if you still need 2 * mapView... or not, since I don't have a chance to try and see it myself.

Comment: I did an edit on the question. I just need to figure out how to center their  x and y again.

Comment: Could you try this as a center ? CGPointMake(_poiTableView.view.frame.origin.x, _poiTableView.view.frame.origin.y - normalHeight * 2.0 / 3);

Comment: I'm almost where I want to be. Only I can't see the end of my tableview. So the users can't see the last 2 items. Because the scroll is on its end.

Comment: Are their centres correct? Or is it about their heights?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59345/discussion-between-edusta-and-user1007522).